How can I use FCM to a/b test different send times for a push notification?
I can't figure out how to use the A/B testing feature in Firebase Cloud Messaging to split my audience in half and test two different send times (11am and 7pm) for a push notification. Any steps you can provide on how to achieve this would be very helpful!
I tried creating an A/B test with two variants for a push notification, but noticed that I can't set different send times for the variants. Do I need to create an a/b test for each send time?
